# How to print specific multi dimensional array java

Tags: java, arrays

Hi so i want to print specific multi dimensional array such as only print with value array "available" but i dont know how to

```
String[][] data = {    {"1. Economy", "Rp 50.000,-", "2%", "Available" }, 
                       {"2. Business", "Rp 100.000,-", "5%", "Not Available"}, 
                       {"3. Executive", "Rp 200.000,-", "7%","Available",}, 
                       {"4. VIP", "Rp 300.000,-", "10%", "Available"}};

for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                System.out.printf("%-15s\n",data[1][i]); 
                System.out.printf("%-15s",data[2][i]);
```

So the output will be

```
  Class         Price        Discount         Availability               
Economy        50000            2%              Available            
Executive      200000           7%              Available               
VIP            300000           10%             Available
```

Comment: You haven't shown any coding attempt. You can find lots of online information about handling multi-dimensional arrays in Java. I would suggest doing some digging for a full account of what that's about. In short, you need to loop through the first dimension of your array, each time printing out each item as determined by the second dimension/index.

Comment: Read up on using either `printf` or `String.format` and then of course you need to fix the values for the first 2 columns which you can do using for instance `split` and `replace` on your strings

Comment: hi sorry i didn't include my coding attempt, but i already fixed that. ok i'll try string.format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could that be what you're trying to achieve?

Usually, if you're working with standard multidimensional arrays, you will need to create two loops. One to iterate 'horizontally' through your dataset, and the other to iterate 'vertically'.

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
        if (data[i][3].equals("Available")) {
            System.out.print(data[i][j]+", ");
        }
     }
     System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answers, it works and really helpful. I forgot to create two loops since it was a multidimensional array.